# How to fix data extraction from Docx table by Python

Tags: python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I need dict from this two columns, but I can't get right keys from first column. Key is taken from header(screenshot attach) that is wrong. Please, How to fix code below?

```
from docx.api import Document

table = document.tables[2]


#Данные из таблицы в список
data = []

keys = None
for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
    text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

    if i == 0:
        keys = tuple(text)
        continue
 
    row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
    data.append(row_data)

data
```

[image]

[image]